# Window disk usage goes to 100% when idle

Tags: chkdsk, idle

My windows pc's disk usage goes to 100% when idle(when pc screen is off and running chrome,photos,etc. not more than 3 apps.) and when I wake the screen it hangs(might be hanging when screen is off also as i cant see it) and then after 10s the disk usage comes back to normal and I get a notification Saying there are disk errors(chkdsk). After shutting it down as normal on next boot it does a chkdsk.

> Sometimes it doesn't force me to do a chkdsk and boots up normally.

Is it a faulty disk? I also ran chkntfs and it show c: is dirty.

Comment: Sounds like Windows' maintenance tasks are running, and a faulty disk causes this issue. I would backup the data first, then check the SMART info and if necessary replace the disk.

Comment: You need to find which process is using the CPU. Let it run in idle for some time, then in Task Manager, Details tab, right-click the headers, choose Select columns, and add "I/O reads" and "l/O writes" for cumulative data. I would also do a deep antivirus scan.

Comment: There's definitely no viruses cause I ran a deep scan recently. I also noticed that sometimes out of the blue "system" or "sysmain" starts using around 70% disk.

Answer (score 0):

> My windows pc's disk usage goes to 100% when idle

You may prevent this from happening by going to `Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings >  Change advanced power settings`. Then, under `Hard Disk > Turn off hard disk after`, enter higher values (e.g. 60 minutes) for both `On battery` and `Plugged in`.

> Is it a faulty disk?

You may go to File Explorer. Right click your (C:) disk and click `Properties > Tools > Error Checking > Check`. If it shows `You don't need to scan this drive`, you can safely ignore the notification. Otherwise, scan the drive and wait for the result. If it reports problems, you need to replace the disk.

Comment: Why would the stopping of the hard disk affect it? And it was set to 20min but it used to hang after just about 2-3mins (does not always hang sometimes hangs while using). Now I've set both to 60 mins.